# Selenium not able to iterate through div's by index

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to iterate and pull data from each div in the below screenshot. The XPath of the first element is:

`//*[@id="ext-gen161"]/div[1]`

[image: html inspect]

My thought is to format and iterate through divs using:

`index = 1`

`'//*[@id="ext-gen161"]/div[' + str(index) + ']'`

`index += 1`

For some reason I can't seem to select the second div via `driver.find_element_by_xpath(formattedXPath)`

I'm just locked onto the first element. Even manually entering the XPath of `//*[@id="ext-gen161"]/div[8]` or so, still returns element present at `div[1]`

Any thoughts?

Would `By.XPATH` work better for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through required elements as:

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ext-gen161"]/div')

print(len(divs))

for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with your approach, just put your xpath in() before indexing it. Like

**(//*[@id="ext-gen161"]//div)[8]**, now it will point to 8th div instead of 1st. Also take a note i have used // instead of /.

```
index = 1
formattedXPath="(//*[@id="ext-gen161"]//div)[" + str(index) + "]"
index += 1
driver.find_element_by_xpath(formattedXPath)
```